# How to create 4KB Linux binaries that render a 3D scene?

Tags: c, linux, linker, executable

I just learned about the [4k demo scene contest](http://www.creativeapplications.net/windows/hartverdrahtet-infinite-complexity-in-4096-bytes/). It consists in creating a 4KB executable which renders a nice 3D scene. The cited demo was build for Windows, so I was wondering, how one could create 4KB OpenGL scenes on Linux.

A bare "hello world" already consumes 8KB:

```
$ cat ex.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
       printf("Hello world\n");
}
$ gcc -Os ex.c -o ex
$ ls -l ex
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cklein cklein 8374 2012-05-11 13:56 ex
```

Comment: Try adding '-v' to the command line and see if it's linking in any libraries statically - you ought to be able to get it smaller than that by linking glibc dynamically. On Windows you also have to contend with it padding everything to 4K segments but I don't think ELF does that.

Comment: It's a lot of specialised work; and they would do shitloads of code generation optimisation ... and possibly use assembly :D

Comment: There was an answer here a minute ago pointing to http://www.int21.de/linux4k/ – seems like a good place to look, not sure why the answer was deleted.

Comment: Someone posted this link then (strangely) deleted their answer, but it is about exactly this: http://www.int21.de/linux4k/

Comment: Most of the time they use assembly and special perpose image generation algorithms, check out this link for a nice intro ;) http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: I think this will give a good answer, rather than an answer here on SO: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: @Jack: Tho you can create 4k demos without assembly. Here's a 4k fractal flame renderer that fully implements Scott Draves paper on flames (of that time; a new version of the paper was released) without assembly: http://phresnel.org/gpl/4k/ntropy2k7/ (source is viewable online). Note that it comes without a main() function but rather uses `_start()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason why with the standard settings you can't make a small tool is that a lot of symbols and references to standard libraries are pulled into your binary. You must be explicit to to remove even that basic stuff.

Here's how I did it:

http://phresnel.org/gpl/4k/ntropy2k7/

### Relevant Options:

Mostly self-explaining:

```
gcc main.c -o fourk0001 -Os -mfpmath=387 \
  -mfancy-math-387 -fmerge-all-constants -fsingle-precision-constant \
  -fno-math-errno -Wall -ldl -ffast-math -nostartfiles -nostdlib  \
  -fno-unroll-loops -fshort-double
```

### Massage:

`strip` helps you get rid of unneeded symbols embedded in your binary:

```
strip -R .note -R .comment -R .eh_frame -R .eh_frame_hdr -s fourk0001
```

### Code:

You may have to tweak and trial and error a lot. Sometimes, a loop gives smaller code, sometimes a call, sometimes a force inlined function. In my code, e.g., instead of having a clean linked list that contains all flame transforms in fancy polymorphic style, I have a fixed array where each element is a big entity containing all parameters, used or unused, as a union of all flames as per Scott Draves flame paper.

Your tricks won't be portable, other versions of g++ might give suboptimal results.

Note that with above parameters, you do not write a `main()` function, but rather a `_start()` function.

Also note that using libraries is a bit different. Instead of linking SDL and standard library functions the classy, convenient way, you must do it manually. E.g.

```
void *libSDL = dlopen( "libSDL.so", RTLD_LAZY );
void *libC = dlopen( "libc.so", RTLD_LAZY );
#if 1
    SDL_SetVideoMode_t sym_SDL_SetVideoMode = dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_SetVideoMode");
    g_sdlbuff = sym_SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT,32,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
#else
    ((SDL_SetVideoMode_t)dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_SetVideoMode"))(WIDTH,HEIGHT,32,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
#endif


//> need malloc, probably kinda craft (we only use it once :| )
//> load some sdl cruft (cruft!)
malloc_t sym_malloc = dlsym( libC, "malloc" );
sym_rand   = dlsym( libC, "rand" );
sym_srand  = dlsym( libC, "srand" );
sym_SDL_Flip          = dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_Flip");
sym_SDL_LockSurface   = dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_LockSurface");
sym_SDL_UnlockSurface = dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_UnlockSurface");
sym_SDL_MapRGB        = dlsym(libSDL, "SDL_MapRGB");
```

And even though no assembler has to be harmed, your code might yield UB.

---

edit:

Oops, I lied about assembly.

```
void _start() {
    ...
    asm( "int $0x80" :: "a"(1), "b"(42) );
}
```

this will make your program return 42.

Comment: I get main.c:(.text+0x83d): undefined reference to `exp'.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I am afraid I lack the time to support other platforms than I wrote it on :/ You might need to `dlsym` the `exp` function from `libm` (which is the math library corresponding to `#include<math.h>`), or maybe you have to tweak some more options. Some math functions are implemented as intrinsics, some may not. As said, if you are into 4k production without too much assembly, your code will probably not be very portable.

Answer (score 8):

[*A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux*](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) is an interesting article that goes through a step-by-step process to create an ELF executable as small as possible.

I don't want to spoil the ending, but the author gets it down to a *lot* smaller than 4K ;)

Comment: You don't spoil the ending because the questioner's target to write a real 4k 3d graphics demo, like on http://www.pouet.net

Comment: Codegolf ELF hello world contest: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/shortest-elf-for-hello-world-n (no rendering).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article in KSplice blog from a while back.  It talks about linking without the standard libraries.

https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free